# How do I convert drupal_goto to 301?

Tags: 7, redirection

Right now I have a redirect in my code:

```
drupal_goto($path);
```

Per [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) `drupal_goto` defaults to a 302 redirect. I want a 301.

However, when I put in:

```
drupal_goto($path, $http_response_code = 302);
```

It gives me an error:

> Argument 2 passed to drupal_goto() must be of the type array, integer given,

But if I try something like:

```
drupal_goto($path, array $options = array(), $http_response_code = 302);
```

...I get this error:

> Unexpected '$options'

How can I properly change `drupal_goto` into a 301 redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're mistaking the function definition for an implementation example.

The function definition describes the arguments to use, but it's not a literal example of how to call it.

So when you want to use the `drupal_goto()` function, instead of this:

```
drupal_goto($path, array $options = array(), $http_response_code = 302);
```

It should look more like this:

```
drupal_goto($path, array(), 301);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
drupal_goto($path = '', array $options = array(), $http_response_code = 302)
```

Initialize $option as empty array something like this

```
$options = array();
$path = <your path>;
drupal_goto($path, $option, 301);
```

Comment: so I need both lines one after the other?

Comment: it should be like this

$options = array();
$path = <your path>;
drupal_goto($path, $option, 301);